# Allure - empty report and outputDirectory is readOnly

Tags: maven, testing, allure

I try to test one site and generate report using allure, but I get empty report. I have noticed that I get warning:

> Parameter 'outputDirectory' is read-only, must not be used in configuration.

If anyone knows how to fix it? Is there only problem with this read-only outrput-directory or something else.

I use commands:

(to test)

> mvn clean test

(to generate test)

> mvn allure:serve

Below is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>JavaDlaTesteraSelenium</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.16.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.24.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.30</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <allureDownloadUrl>
                    https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/releases/download/2.7.0/allure-2.7.0.zip
                </allureDownloadUrl>
                <reportVersion>2.7.0</reportVersion>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/allure-reports/</outputDirectory>
                <resultsDirectory>${project.basedir}/allure-results/</resultsDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>5.7.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

I get this on console:

```
Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------< org.example:JavaTesting >-----------------
[INFO] Building JavaTesting 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- allure:2.9:serve (default-cli) @ JavaTesting ---
[WARNING]  Parameter 'outputDirectory' is read-only, must not be used in configuration
[INFO] Allure installation directory C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\JavaTesting/.allure
[INFO] Try to finding out allure 2.7.0
[INFO] Generate Allure report (serve) with version 2.7.0
[INFO] Generate Allure report to C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\JavaTesting\target\site/allure-maven-plugin
[INFO] Found results directory C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\JavaTesting\allure-results
[INFO] Can't find information about categories.
[INFO] Generate report to C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\JavaTesting\target\site\allure-maven-plugin
Generating report to temp directory...
Report successfully generated to C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\2610920358019135712\allure-report
Starting web server...
2024-01-14 14:26:16.190:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1667ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
```